# How to Edit DSResponse data

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am trying to add new blank row in dropdown menu of `ComboBoxItem`, for which data is coming from database. blank row with value "-1" or `null` to response of `DSResponse`.

```
        Criteria c2 = new Criteria();
    OptionListDataSource attrTypeds = OptionListDataSource
            .getInstance(FieldNames.ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_FIELD);
    attrTypeds.fetchData (c2, new DSCallback() {

        @Override
        public void execute(final DSResponse response,
                final Object rawData, final DSRequest request) {
            Record[] recList = response.getData();

            if (recList != null) {
                StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();


                int recListLength = recList.length;
                Window.alert("Lenght of Response is : "+recListLength);
                for(int i=0;i<recListLength;i++){
                    Window.alert("Data at "+i+" : "+recList[i].getAttribute(FieldNames.ID_FIELD));  
                    Record record = recList[i];
                    JavaScriptObject js = record.getJsObj();
                    JSONObject jsonn = new JSONObject(js);
                    builder.append(jsonn.toString());
                }
                Window.alert("JSON Response : "+builder);
                recList[recListLength+1].setAttribute(FieldNames.ID_FIELD, "-1");
                Window.alert("Updated lenght of Response is : "+recList.length);
                Window.alert("Updated Value at last position : "+recList[recList.length].getAttribute(FieldNames.ID_FIELD));

                initialValuesMap.put(FieldNames.ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_ID_FIELD,recList[recList.length].getAttribute(FieldNames.ID_FIELD));

            }

            form.editNewRecord(initialValuesMap);
        }
    });
```

I can't see my alert after `Window.alert("JSON Response : "+builder);` this statement. What wrong I am doing ? I just want to add blank/`null` data to `Record[] recList`. Also, is there any `Criteria` for this. I am using smartgwt version 3

Answer (score 0):

If you use a ***SelectItem*** instead of the ***ComboBoxItem*** the blank option will come by default and you dont need to do anything.

Comment: you are right, but for this whole implementation needs to be change.  `Record recList[] = response.getRecord();
Record blankRecord = new Record();
Record recTemp[] = new Record[recList.length];
for(Record rec : recList){
 recTemp.getAttribute(rec.getAttribute("OLDKEY"));
 }
recTemp[recList.length-1] = blankRecord;
recTemp[recList.length-1].setAttribute("KEY1","Value1");
recTemp[recList.length-1].setAttribute("KEY2","Value2");
` I tried this approach this adds the value but won't reflect on UI